# Relation between Bombieri theorem and p-adic squares

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Koblitz states in his book on p-adic numbers on page 84:

> Suppose that $\alpha \in \mathbb Q$ is such that $1 + \alpha$ is the square of a nonzero rational number $a/b$.
>   Let $S$ be the set of all primes $p$ for which the binomial series for $(1 + \alpha)^{1/2}$ converges in $|\cdot|_p$.
>   There is no $\alpha$ other than $8$, $16/9$, $3$, $5/4$ for which $(1 + \alpha)^{1/2}$ converges to the same value in $|\cdot|_p$ for all $p \in S$.

Why is this an example of a very general theory of E. Bombieri? What does the theory (or theorem) say and what are its possible connections with p-adic numbers? Is it the Bombieri–Vinogradov theorem from analytic number theory?

Comment: In the marked text you forgot the sentence " This is one example of a very general theory of E. Bombieri", which is stated at the end of exercise $11$, (e). I first wondered who had made this remark. Bombieri has more theorems, by the way.

Comment: Gouvea seemingly reiterates this attribution ("According to Koblitz, this is a special case of a theory due to Bombieri") but delves no deeper in the Hints and Comments to an earlier version of his $p$-adic text.